# Java - Method structure execution

Tags: java

I am going through the University of Helsinki's Java course and I have a question on one of the examples.

The code in question:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UserInterface {
private Scanner reader;

public UserInterface(Scanner reader) {
    this.reader = reader;
}

public void start() {
    while (true) {
        String command = reader.nextLine();

        if (command.equals("end")) {
            break;
        } else {
            handleCommand(command);
        }
    }
}

public void handleCommand(String command) {
    if (command.equals("buy")) {
        String input = readInput("What to buy: ");
        System.out.println("Bought!");
    } else if (command.equals("sell")) {
        String input = readInput("What to sell: ");
        System.out.println("Sold!");
    }
}

public String readInput(String question) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print(question);
        String line = reader.nextLine();

        if (line.equals("carrot")) {
            return line;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item not found!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

If you choose to buy or sell something that isn't a carrot why does it not run the line directly below the input line in the handleCommand method (printing Bought! or Sold!)? I don't understand how it terminates the conditional in the case that a carrot is not bought or sold. How is the readInput method manipulating the handleCommand method here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The function `readInput()` is rather oddly defined: it will only return if you enter *carrot*.

`readInput()` contains a `while` loop that keeps looping until the user enters *carrot*, otherwise it says *Item not found!* and tries again. The output lines in `handleCommand()` are only executed when `readInput()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your readInput() method returns the String "line" only if the user inputs "carrot" otherwise it will keep on going inside the else part and continue printing "Item not found!". But instead of System.out.println("Item not found!") ,
if you just return that statement then either "carrot" or "Item not found!" will be returned and stored in the "input" variable of handleCommand() method. In that case now it will print your "Bought!" or "Sold!" print statement irrespective whether you choose "carrot" or something else